# create SOCK_RAW socket just for sending data without any recvform()

Tags: linux, sockets, raw-sockets

If I create a socket whose type is SOCK_RAW only to send some data without receiving any data, is there any problem when kernel continue to receive network packets and copy its datagram to somebuffer (of application?). In other words, after the somebuffer is filled what will happened? error or ignore?

I don't know how to prevent kernel from delivering the copy of datagram to my application.

Reference http://sock-raw.org/papers/sock_raw 0x4 raw_input

After the IP layer processes
a new incoming IP datagram, it calls ip_local_deliver_finish() kernel function
which is responsibe for calling a registered transport protocol handler by 
inspecting the protocol field of the IP header (remember from above). However 
before it delivers the datagram to the handler, it checks every time if an 
application has created a raw socket with the *same* protocol number. If there
is one or more such applications, it makes a copy of the datagram and delivers 
it to them as well.

Comment: What does 'copy to somebuffer from kernel' mean? It's the other way around when sending: the data is copied from your application into the socket send buffer.

Comment: `if an application has created a raw socket with the same protocol number. If there is one or more such applications, it makes a copy of the datagram and delivers it to them as well.'; The application will call recvfrom() to receive the copy. the question is that I don't call recvform() copy just use the socket to send raw packets. So where the copy store? will be filled? and then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **shutdown(2)** in order to shutdown reception part of the socket.
See [shutdown man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shutdown)

**EDIT :** I found that **shutdown** only works on connected (ie TCP) sockets.
With Raw socket, there are 2 possibilities :

- Receive data into a temporary buffer (with **recv**) and discard them (perhaps in an other thread)
- If I remember well, when the socket buffer is full, incoming data are automatically discarded (and data in the buffer aren't modified), so you can set the socket reception buffer size to 0 (and increase it later if needed).

Here's how to set reception buffer size to 0 :

```
int opt = 0;
setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &opt, sizeof(opt));
```

**TEST**

```
/**
 * @file raw_print_pkt.c
 * @brief 
 * @author Airead Fan <fgh1987168@gmail.com>
 * @date 2012/08/22 12:35:22
 */

#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int s;
    ssize_t rn;                 /* receive number */
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    char packet[4096];
    int count;

    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) {
        perror("error:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(packet, 0, sizeof(packet));
    socklen_t *len = (socklen_t *)sizeof(saddr);
    int fromlen = sizeof(saddr);
    int opt = 0;

    count = 0;
    while(1) {
        if ((rn = recvfrom(s, (char *)&packet, sizeof(packet), 0,
                           (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, &fromlen)) < 0)
            perror("packet receive error:");
        if (rn == 0) {
            printf("the peer has performed an orderly shutdown\n");
            break;
        }

        printf("[%d] rn = %lu \n", count++, rn);

        if (count == 16) {
            if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0) {
                perror("setsocketopt failed");
            } else {
                fprintf(stdout, "setsocketopt successful\n");
            }
            // int shutdown(int sockfd, int how);
            /* if (shutdown(s, SHUT_RD) < 0) {
             *     perror("shutdown failed");
             * } */
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**TEST 2 (same includes):**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int s;
ssize_t rn;                 /* receive number */
char packet[4096];
int count;

if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) {
    perror("error:");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

memset(packet, 0, sizeof(packet));
int opt = 0;
count = 0;

//Set recv buffer size
if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0) {
    perror("setsocketopt failed");
} else {
    fprintf(stdout, "setsocketopt successful\n");
}

//10 seconds countdown
int i = 10;
while(i > 0)
{
    printf("\r%d              ", i);
    fflush(stdout);
    i--;
    sleep(1);
}
printf("\n");
while(1) {
    if ((rn = recv(s, (char *)&packet, sizeof(packet), 0)) <= 0)
        perror("packet receive error:");

    printf("[%d] rn = %lu \n", count++, rn);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Here's how to proceed with test 2 :

First of all, set the buffer size to 4096 (or bigger if you have a lot of traffic on your network). Compile and launch. During the 10 seconds before starting receiving data, send a lot of data to the socket. After the 10 seconds, the program will receive everything you sent during the countdown.

After that, set the buffer size to 0. Proceed as previously. After the 10 seconds, the program won't receive the data you sent during the countdown. But if you send data while it's in **recvfrom**, it will read them normally.

Comment: Simple and effective! But when I try it, **shutdown failed: Transport endpoint is not connected**. although shutdown(2) failed, the recvfrom(2) returns 0 stands for the peer has performed an orderly shutdown. -_-! is there other problem?

Comment: i edited your answer for adding a test program. set SO_RECV doesn't works well.

Comment: I made some tests with the code you provided. It seems that when buffer size is 0, you can still receive data, but these data don't come from the buffer, but directly from the socket. So data are received only when you are reading the socket, otherwise they are discarded.

Comment: Added a modified test so you can check what I said

Comment: That was a very interresting case !

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand what you want! if you want just to inject some packets, it's simple:

```
#include<netinet/tcp.h> /* TCP header */
#include<netinet/ip.h>  /* IP header */

/* Checksum compute function */
/* source : http://www.winpcap.org/pipermail/winpcap-users/2007-July/001984.html */
unsigned short checksum(unsigned short *buffer, int size)
{
    unsigned long cksum=0;
    while(size >1)
    {
        cksum+=*buffer++;
        size -=sizeof(unsigned short);
    }
    if(size)
        cksum += *(UCHAR*)buffer;

    cksum = (cksum >> 16) + (cksum & 0xffff);
    cksum += (cksum >>16);
    return (unsigned short)(~cksum);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char packet_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in sin;     
    struct iphdr *ip_header;    /* IP header */
    struct tcphdr *tcp_header;  /* TCP header */
    int flag = 1;

    /* Creating RAW socket */
    int raw_socket = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);

    ip_header = (struct iphdr *) packet_buffer;

    tcp_header = (struct tcphdr *) (packet_buffer + sizeof (struct ip));

    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(PORT_NUMBER);
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr (IP_ADDRESS);

    /* Zeroing the bbuffer */ 
    memset (packet_buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

    /* Construct your IP Header */
    ip_header->ihl = 5;
    ip_header->version = 4;
    ip_header->tos = 0;
    ip_header->tot_len = sizeof (struct ip) + sizeof (struct tcphdr);
    ip_header->id = htonl(CHOOSE_PACKET_ID);
    ip_header->frag_off = 0;
    ip_header->ttl = 255;
    ip_header->protocol = 6;    /* TCP. Change to 17 if you want UDP */
    ip_header->check = 0;
    ip_header->saddr = inet_addr (SOURCE_IP_ADDRESS_TO_SPOOF);
    ip_header->daddr = sin.sin_addr.s_addr;

    /* Construct your TCP Header */
    tcp_header->source = htons (SOURCE);
    tcp_header->dest = htons(DEST);
    tcp_header->seq = random();
    tcp_header->ack_seq = 0;
    tcp_header->doff = 0;
    tcp_header->syn = 1; 
    tcp_header->window = htonl(65535);
    tcp_header->check = 0;
    tcp_header->urg_ptr = 0;

    /* IP Checksum */
    ip_header->check = checksum((unsigned short *) packet_buffer, ip_header->tot_len >> 1);

    if (setsockopt(raw_socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &flag, sizeof(flag)) < 0)
    {
        /* ERROR handling */
    }

    while (1)
    {
        /* Send the packet */
    if (sendto(raw_socket, packet_buffer, ip_header->tot_len, 0,  (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof (sin)) < 0)
    {
        /* ERROR handling */
    }
    /* The rest of your need */
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Once your application calls `raw_socket = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);', the kernel will deliver all tcp packets to `raw_socket' even if the application doesn't invoke recvfrom() system call. for example, after the application sleep 100 seconds, the recvfrom() will receive all tcp packets which the kernel delivers during the 100 seconds. Further more, although you call recvfrom() in 1000 seconds, you will still receive all tcp packet form the point (create IPPROTO_TCP sockets) to now. So the tcp packets must be stored in someplace. Can the someplace be filled with tcp packets?